# Получить значение текущего пользователя и отобразить в фильтре ModelChoice

Tags: python, django, form

```
 serviceForModal = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Services.objects.filter(owner=),
                                         required=False)
```

В QuerySet в фильтре нужно указать, что owner=текущий пользователь
request.session,как я понял, в формах нет. Чем можно заменить?

views.py

```
def log_in(request):
if 'username' not in request.session:
    return render(request, "login.html", {})
else:
    form = AccessesForm(user=request.user)
    allAccesses = Accesses.objects.filter(owner=request.session['username'])
    allServices = Services.objects.filter(owner=request.session['username'])
    return render(request, "index.html",
                  {'accessForm': form, 'Accesses': allAccesses, 'sForm': ServicesForm,
                   'Services': allServices})
```

forms.py

```
class AccessesForm(forms.Form):

title = forms.CharField(max_length=50, min_length=10)
service = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Services.objects.all())
serviceForModal = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Services.objects.all(), required=False)
username = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
usernameForModal = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(), required=False)
password = forms.CharField(min_length=6, max_length=200, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
comment = forms.CharField(max_length=150, min_length=10, required=False)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if user:
        self.fields['serviceForModal'].queryset = Services.objects.filter(owner=user)
```

index.html

```
<p>Выбрать другой сервис:</p>
{{ form.serviceForModal }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**forms.py**

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    service_for_modal = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Services.objects.all(), required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user:
            self.fields['service_for_modal'].queryset = Services.objects.filter(owner=user)
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def some_view(request):
    form = SomeForm(user=request.user)
    ...
```

Comment: Я немного туплю и пока не могу понять, как это интегрировать в свой проект? Можно ещё подробностей?

Comment: Определяете в форме конструктор принимающий пользователя, а при создании экземпляра формы передаёте в неё текущего юзера.

Comment: Поправил вопрос. в index.html, в поле "Выбрать другой сервис" должен выводить этот самый select, но безуспешно, что не так делаю?

Comment: Что значит безуспешно? Он вообще не отображается? Он нефильтрованный и в нём все сервисы? Он пустой?

Comment: Не отображается

Comment: Видать, в `request.session` нет элемента с ключом "username". У вас в этом случае на страницу форма вообще не передаётся.

Comment: username в request.session храниться в виде: request.session['username']. И попадает он туда во вьюшки аутентификации, где заноситься в виде: request.session['username'] = username

Comment: Попробуйте поменять `{{ form.serviceForModal }}` на `{{ accessForm.serviceForModal }}`.

Comment: Ураа! Вы гений! Спасибо огромное!